# How to set breakpoints on every line of the code (delphi)?

Tags: delphi, debugging, breakpoints

I have a very big code, and I need to debug it fully, so I need to set breakpoint on every line of the code. Ho to do this?

Comment: F7 not good enough for stepping line by line? :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson make that an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to set breakpoints, `F7` is the shortcut for "Debugger step into" which will do exactly what you're trying to do, step through the program stopping at every line.

If you want to skip certain method calls, `F8` ("Debugger step over") can also be helpful.

Comment: Let me add F4 for "Execute to cursor".